# Groovy pre-recieve hook to block push -f (forced pushes)

Tags: groovy, gitblit

I want to implement block force push mechanism in our gitblit repository. I want a pre-receive groovy script to do so. Could someone please help on the same. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Please ta a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question. A well-formed question has more chance to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid force pushes is to assign [RW permissions rather than RW+](http://gitblit.com/administration.html#H5).  If you really want to grant RW+ permission but block it's use, then you'll have to implement a variation of [this hook script](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/distrib/data/groovy/blockpush.groovy).

Comment: I wanted to achieve by using groovy script. is there any possibility?